# Python - parse xml with lxml trouble

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I've found a lot of questions on this issue but nothing I saw fits mine. I'm new to lxml so need some help.

my users.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
    <user>
    <login>elena</login>
    <password>elena</password>
    <group>1</group>
    </user>

    <user>
    <login>anele</login>
    <password>anele</password>
    <group>2</group>
    </user>
</root>
```

the trouble function:

```
def analize_data(login):
   doc = etree.parse("/myapp/users.xml")   
   for elem in doc.iter(tag='login'):       
       if elem.text == login:
          parent = elem.getparent()
          group = etree.SubElement(parent, 'group')
          return group.text
```

**What I need:**
to find a user tag with login passed to function and get the text of *group* subelement of this user. But this function returns None when testing. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

I'm new to all these things, so need help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
group = parent.iterchildren(tag="group").next()
```

`etree.SubElement` does something completely different:

> This function creates an element instance, and appends it to an existing element.

Which is clearly not what you want.